# Warning passing argument 2 of 'finder' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to pass a user entered variable "find" into this function and return the subscript location of the number (in an existing array)  that the user entered. I saw some other posts about this but couldn't understand really what was being explained. Sorry, beginner student.

It isn't quite complete but I cannot compile due to a couple of errors that I am not sure about.

1. Warning passing argument 2 of 'finder' makes pointer from integer without a cast. Its pointing at:

`num_loc = finder(find, sort_num[10]);`

Here I am setting "num_loc" to the return of "where" in the function
    
     `num_loc = finder(find, sort_num[10]);
     printf( "\nYour number is located in memory location %d of the array",num_loc );`

2. "[Note] expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'" which is pointing to my function prototype.

   `//fprototype outside the main at the beginning of the file
   int finder(int f,int x[]);`

Here is my function:

```
//function located at the end of the file outside the main
int finder(int f, int x[])
{
    int found = 0;
    int where;
    int i = 0;

    while (found != 1){
        if (x[i] == f){
            found = 1;
            where = i;
            return where;
        }
        else{
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel stupid.... that was all it was.. Thank you..

Comment: `int x[]` is an `int *` (a pointer, or an array in this context). You call it with `sort[10]` which is probably an `int`, so the warning is logical: you make a pointer (the `int*` needed) from an integer value (the `sort[10]` you give).

Comment: the 'location in memory'' in your question/printf() statement seems to indicate a memory address, however, `%d` is for printing integers.  For printing an address, use: `%p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num_loc = finder(find, sort_num[10]);
```

is equivalent to

```
int num = sort_num[10];       // Problem. Accessing array out of bounds.
num_loc = finder(find, num);  // Problem. Using an `int` when an `int*` is expected.
                              // That's what the compiler is complaining about.
```

You need to use just `sort_num` in the call to `finder`.

```
num_loc = finder(find, sort_num);
```

The real solution involves changing `finder` to accept another argument that indicates the number of elements in `sort_num`. Otherwise, you run the risk of accessing the array out of bounds. It can also be simplified quite a bit.

```
int finder(int f, int x[], int arraySize)
{
   for ( int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i )
   {
      if (x[i] == f)
      {
         return i;
      }
   }

   // Not found
   return -1;
}
```

and then call it with:

```
num_loc = finder(find, sort_num, 10);
```

Comment: Alright. Seems to be functioning aside from not ever finding the number in the array that was passed. I think that is probably a whole other questions by itself though.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first part of your function definition:

`int finder(int f, int x[])`

Your second argument is an int pointer, which the compiler is telling you by saying :

`expected 'int *'`

You called your function with this:

`num_loc = finder(find, sort_num[10]);`

If sort_num is an integer array, then sort_num[10] evaluates to the integer at the 11th place in that array. So you're passing your finder function that integer, instead of an int pointer. If sort_num is an integer array, re-write your call as:

`num_loc = finder(find, sort_num);`

This way you will be passing an int pointer that holds the address of the first element in the sort_num array.

Comment: Appreciate your help! Everyone was very helpful.